# Running an executable which is compiled with CMake in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

I am trying to compile a simple C++ program with CMake in Windows and making it usable by double clicking. My compiler is g++ and I use it under MSYS2. Therefore, I add -static flag in target_link_libraries command. Until now, everything looks OK, the program is compiled and executed by double clicking. When I also define an icon for the executable my problem arises. The program is compiled and I can execute it under Eclipse. However, I cannot run it by double clicking. As well, nothing happens when I run it in command line. By the way, the executable has the icon that I defined.

Here is my Cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

set(APP_ICON_RESOURCE_WINDOWS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/appicon.rc")

project(MyProject VERSION 1.0 DESCRIPTION "MyProject")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp)

add_executable(MyProject WIN32 "${SOURCE_FILES}" ${APP_ICON_RESOURCE_WINDOWS })
#add_executable(MyProject "${SOURCE_FILES}")   # this line has no problem but no icon

target_compile_options(MyProject PUBLIC -g3 -O0)
target_link_libraries(MyProject -static)
```

So, I wonder how I can achieve to create a statically linked executable with a default icon.

Comment: What compiler are you using? What does the program do? Please show a [mre]. At a guess you're using gcc and the mingw runtime dlls are not on your path

Comment: Is your entry point ``main()`` or ``WinMain()`` ? I think specifying ``WIN32`` implies the latter. Can you try without ``WIN32`` ?

Answer (score 0):

When the object file for the icon is created separately, it works ([just like here](https://gist.github.com/Niakr1s/749a88643e154320768e5972c80347cb)). To do this, I used windres application to embed the icon:

```
windres appicon.rc -o MyIcon.o
```

Then, I removed WIN32 and icon related entries in CMake. Now, the Cmake file is just like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

project(MyProject VERSION 1.0 DESCRIPTION "MyProject")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_FILES ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp)

add_executable(MyProject "${SOURCE_FILES}" MyIcon.o)

target_compile_options(MyProject PUBLIC -g3 -O0)
target_link_libraries(MyProject -static)
```